# count lines by hour

Tags: linux, unix, awk

What would be the command to count how many times we saw certain line by hour or by minute?

File:

```
Nov 26 08:50:51
Nov 26 08:50:51
Nov 26 08:51:09
Nov 26 08:51:09
Nov 26 08:51:09
Nov 26 08:51:09
Nov 26 08:51:40
```

Output I would like to see:

by minute:

```
Nov 26 08:50    2
Nov 26 08:51    5
```

by hour:

```
Nov 26 08       7
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers :) helped a lot.

Comment: What if the date changed? Are you looking for output for 08:50 across all days, or for 08:50 each day?

Answer (score 35):

This can be done with `uniq`:

```
$ uniq -w9 -c file       # by hour
      7 Nov 26 08:50:51
$ uniq -w12 -c file      # by minute
      2 Nov 26 08:50:51
      5 Nov 26 08:51:09
```

`-w` compare no more than the first `n` characters.

`-c` prefix lines by the number of occurrences.

Comment: "but what if days < 10 are written without leading 0 ? oh wait o_O It will work X_X ". Good job +1

Comment: This is great, but I have to point out that this solution is Linux-only.  The `uniq` in *BSD (including OSX) doesn't include a `-w` option.

Comment: @ghoti it would be more accurate to say this solution requires GNU's implementation of uniq which can be installed on any OS.

Comment: True enough.  If you install coreutils in FreeBSD, the command you'd want is actually called `guniq`.  I add this only for posterity.  The answer is still excellent.  :-)

Comment: Works on Solaris as well.  Assuming this is to count files by date/time, here is an example starting from the ls.  This particular example counts by 10s of hours.    ls -l /foo/bar* | nawk '{print $6 " " $7 " " $8}'  | uniq -w7 -c

Answer (score 2):

By hour:

```
awk '{split($3,a,":");b[$1" "$2" "a[1]]++}END{for(i in b)print i,b[i]}' your_file
```

tested Below:

```
> awk '{split($3,a,":");b[$1" "$2" "a[1]":"a[2]]++}END{for(i in b)print i,b[i]}' temp
Nov 26 08:50 2
Nov 26 08:51 5
>
```

By minute:

```
awk '{split($3,a,":");b[$1" "$2" "a[1]":"a[2]]++}END{for(i in b)print i,b[i]}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> awk '{split($3,a,":");b[$1" "$2" "a[1]]++}END{for(i in b)print i,b[i]}' temp
Nov 26 08 7
```

Answer (score 2):

the awk one-liner gives you count by hour and min in one shot:

```
awk -F: '{h[$1]++;m[$1":"$2]++;}END{for(x in h)print x,h[x]; print "---"; for(x in m)print x,m[x]}' file
```

test

```
kent$  echo "Nov 26 08:50:51
Nov 26 08:50:51
Nov 26 08:51:09
Nov 26 08:51:09
Nov 26 08:51:09
Nov 26 08:51:09
Nov 26 08:51:40"|awk -F: '{h[$1]++;m[$1":"$2]++;}END{for(x in h)print x,h[x]; print "---"; for(x in m)print x,m[x]}'
```

output

```
Nov 26 08 7
---
Nov 26 08:50 2
Nov 26 08:51 5
```

Comment: Thanks for this, just what I needed. doing a pipe and sort '| sort' can get everything in the right order too.